# Key binding to popup menu item in eclipse Helios?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, keyboard-shortcuts

In our project at work, they have written one plug-in for eclipse helios. They have used the 
objectContribution for adding the popups and written respective action classes for them.
I am trying to add the shortcut key for one of the popup menu item in project explorer. 
But I read here http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/tree/172398/#page_top that there is no way to call key bindings from objectContribution and need to migrate it to handlers/commands.

Is there any other way to bind keys to popups instead of migrate them to handlers?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, objectContributions cannot accept keybindings.  From legacy action extension points, only actionSets accept keybindings correctly.

The other option available (as mentioned) is to provide a handler for the command you want.  The handler won't interfere with the objectContribution behaviour (the objectContribution action delegate class will still be called directly from the menu item, the handler would be called when using a keybinding).

PW

Comment: Thanks a lot Paul for the answer. I am a newbie in plugin development. I'm sorry, did get the last sentence in your comment. Please elaborate it for me. Thanks in advance!